# Which of these pieces of CSS is more efficient for achieving the desired result?

Tags: css, performance, optimization, browser

Which of the following will take less time to be read by the browser? And are there any additional micro-optimizations that I can make (other than, of course, eliminating whitespace)?

**Option 1:**

```css
        ol.red-numbers > li:before { color: #A71930; padding-right: 5px; }
        ol.red-numbers > li:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "1"; }
        ol.red-numbers > li:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "2"; }
        ol.red-numbers > li:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "3"; }
```

**Option 2:**

```css
        ol.red-numbers > li:nth-of-type(1):before { color: #A71930; padding-right: 5px; content: "1"; }
        ol.red-numbers > li:nth-of-type(2):before { color: #A71930; padding-right: 5px; content: "2"; }
        ol.red-numbers > li:nth-of-type(3):before { color: #A71930; padding-right: 5px; content: "3"; }
```

Comment: "And are there any additional micro-optimizations that I can make?" At least you realize what you're doing, but... don't you have anything better to do?

Comment: @BoltClock A wise man once said, "Micro-optimization is the greatest good."

Comment: I've never seen a list-item as a direct child of another list-item and I would be surprised if that's valid mark-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..are there any additional micro-optimizations that I can make?

Since you're selecting elements based on their index, and giving them a corresponding `content` value, you could use [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) to do this automatically assuming this pattern is linear (as you CSS suggests):

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item 0;
}
ol > li {
    counter-increment: item;
}
ol.red-numbers > li:before {
    content: counter(item) " pseudo-element ";
    color: #A71930;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="red-numbers">
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The question rises *if* this is indeed an optimisation. Considering that this code requires calculations (count) by the browser rather than only painting the canvas I am curious to know if your approach is indeed faster and not - as I would expect on larger scale - slower.

Comment: @BramVanroy Good point. But considering the OP mentioned "eliminating whitespace", I presumed that they meant reducing the bytes in the stylesheet. Not sure, though. It's a little odd considering that list are automatically numbered.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive analysis done by Steve souders.Check out this article

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/.

> The biggest surprise is how small the delta is from the baseline to
>   the most complex, worst performing test page. The average slowdown
>   across all browsers is 50 ms.

So practically it wont matter i guess.